# Compiling Blender - Python Error

Tags: python, compile

I'm a noob when it comes to compiling. I've followed the instructions for compiling Blender on OpenSuse Linux.

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Linux/OpenSUSE

I downloaded the sources.
I downloaded the libraries.

But when I follow the Update and Build instructions

```
cd /home/myprofile/bin/blender-git/blender/
make update
```

I'm given the following error:

```
python3 ./build_files/utils/make_update.py
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = '/usr/local/lib/python:/usr/lib64/python/'
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/lib/python',
    '/usr/lib64/python/',
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib64/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
  File "/usr/lib64/python/encodings/__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00007f9baaa00740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
make: *** [GNUmakefile:504: update] Error 1
```

Comment: @robert-gützkow thanks for cleaning up the post, but but do you have an answer to my question?

Comment: This is likely related to your `PYTHONPATH`, possibly due to one of the paths referencing Python 2.7 libs. I would try to use `unset PYTHONPATH` to temporarily clear the environment variable and check if this resolves the issue.

Comment: @robert-gützkow thank you! That was the solution to the issue. Blender compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `PYTHONPATH`. It seems that `/usr/lib64/python/` points to the libraries of Python 2.7, which results in the aforementioned error. The `PYTHONPATH` environment variable can be temporarily removed for the current terminal with the command `unset PYTHONPATH` after which you should be able to run `make update` successfully.

Comment: A proper fix would be to either adjust the `PYTHONPATH` so you're able to run Python 3.x or set up and activate a virtual environment for Python 3.x.

Comment: I'll have to research that.

Comment: would using `update-alternatives` suffice? With this I can switch between the three versions of Python on my machine.

Comment: @leoplaw Since I can't tell with certainty what the original source of the issue was that resulted in the improperly set path, I don't know if this will solve the problem. I can only suggest you to try it on your system.